# 403 error while sending email from AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send emails from the sandbox version of AWS SES from a verified identity. I've used Java V2 SDK of AWS SES to implement this. I'm getting 403 error while sending email even after providing full access permission to the IAM user.

**Access given to the IAM user:**

```
AmazonSESFullAccess

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error received at the client side:

> User `arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/iam-username' is not authorized to perform` ses:SendEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:region-id:XXXXXXXXX:identity/sender-email@domain.com' (Service: Ses, Status Code: 403, Request ID: a7287c61-dca1-48b5-87c0-b3b0df00a35e)

**Edit #1:**

```java
AwsCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create("awsAccessKey", "awsSecretKey");
sesClient = SesClient.builder().credentialsProvider(() -> credentials).region(region).build();
Destination destination = Destination.builder().toAddresses("verified-receiver@test.com").build();
Content content = Content.builder().data("some html content").build();
Content subject = Content.builder().data("some subject").build();
Body body = Body.builder().html(content).build();
Message msg = Message.builder().subject(subject).body(body).build();

SendEmailRequest emailRequest =
    SendEmailRequest.builder()
        .destination(destination)
        .message(msg)
        .source("verified-sender@test.com")
        .build();

SendEmailResponse response = sesClient.sendEmail(emailRequest);
```

Is there anything I'm missing here which is causing this problem?

Comment: InvalidClientTokenId
The X.509 certificate or AWS access key ID provided does not exist in our records.

MissingAuthenticationToken
The request must contain either a valid (registered) AWS access key ID or X.509 certificate.

HTTP Status Code: 403 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html

Comment: @Sri, the error calls out that the iam-username is not authorized to perform the action. So, the access key id configuration is valid.

Comment: Please post your code too? are you sending emails using lambda?

Comment: Are you using the same region where you created you created the keys right? Also you mean 'to' a verified email ?

Comment: @Riz, i'm sending mail to a verified address. I'm using testing the keys from my local. It is working from my local to access S3 storage using the same keys.

Comment: `It is working from my local to access S3 storage using the same keys.` so you are running this code in lambda right?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra, i'm not running it from lambda. I'm testing it from my local machine itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The IAM user had permission boundary to S3 alone. This was causing 403 error and the error message was not very informative.